# can't get returned values in a structure in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I'm having this code:

```
//
//  Measurement.swift
//  BicycleSpeed

    import Foundation
    import CoreBluetooth

    // CSC Measurement
    // https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.csc_measurement.xml
    //
    //  Flags : 1 byte.  Bit 0: Wheel. Bit 1: Crank
    //  Cumulative Wheel revolutions: 4 bytes uint32
    //  Last wheel event time: 2 bytes. uint16 (1/1024s)
    //  Cumulative Crank revolutions: 2 bytes uint16
    //  Last cranck event time: 2 bytes. uint16 (1/1024s)


    struct Measurement : CustomDebugStringConvertible {

      let hasWheel:Bool
      let hasCrank:Bool
      let cumulativeWheel:UInt32
      let lastWheelEventTime:TimeInterval
      let cumulativeCrank:UInt16
      let lastCrankEventTime:TimeInterval
      let wheelSize:UInt32


      init(data:Data, wheelSize:UInt32) {

        self.wheelSize = wheelSize
        // Flags
        var flags:UInt8=0
        (data as NSData).getBytes(&flags, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 1))

        hasWheel = ((flags & BTConstants.WheelFlagMask) > 0)
        hasCrank = ((flags & BTConstants.CrankFlagMask) > 0)

        var wheel:UInt32=0
        var wheelTime:UInt16=0
        var crank:UInt16=0
        var crankTime:UInt16=0

        var currentOffset = 1
        var length = 0

        if ( hasWheel ) {

          length = MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size
          (data as NSData).getBytes(&wheel, range: NSRange(location: currentOffset, length: length))
          currentOffset += length

          length = MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size
          (data as NSData).getBytes(&wheelTime, range: NSRange(location: currentOffset, length: length))
          currentOffset += length
        }

        if ( hasCrank ) {

          length = MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size
          (data as NSData).getBytes(&crank, range: NSRange(location: currentOffset, length: length))
          currentOffset += length

          length = MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size
          (data as NSData).getBytes(&crankTime, range: NSRange(location: currentOffset, length: length))
          currentOffset += length
        }

        cumulativeWheel     = CFSwapInt32LittleToHost(wheel)
        lastWheelEventTime  = TimeInterval( Double(CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(wheelTime))/BTConstants.TimeScale)
        cumulativeCrank     = CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(crank)
        lastCrankEventTime  = TimeInterval( Double(CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(crankTime))/BTConstants.TimeScale)

      }

      func timeIntervalForCurrentSample( _ current:TimeInterval, previous:TimeInterval ) -> TimeInterval {
        var timeDiff:TimeInterval = 0
        if( current >= previous ) {
            timeDiff = current - previous
        }
        else {
          // passed the maximum value
          timeDiff =  ( TimeInterval((Double( UINT16_MAX) / BTConstants.TimeScale)) - previous) + current
        }
        return timeDiff

      }

      func valueDiffForCurrentSample<T:UnsignedInteger>( _ current:T, previous:T , max:T) -> T {

        var diff:T = 0
        if  ( current >= previous ) {
          diff = current - previous
        }
        else {
           diff = ( max - previous ) + current
        }
        return diff
      }


      func valuesForPreviousMeasurement( _ previousSample:Measurement? ) -> ( cadenceinRPM:Double?, distanceinMeters:Double?, speedInMetersPerSecond:Double?)? {


        var distance:Double?, cadence:Double?, speed:Double?
        guard let previousSample = previousSample else {
          return nil
        }
        if ( hasWheel && previousSample.hasWheel ) {
          let wheelTimeDiff = timeIntervalForCurrentSample(lastWheelEventTime, previous: previousSample.lastWheelEventTime)
          let valueDiff = valueDiffForCurrentSample(cumulativeWheel, previous: previousSample.cumulativeWheel, max: UInt32.max)

          distance = Double( valueDiff * wheelSize) / 1000.0 // distance in meters
          if  distance != nil  &&  wheelTimeDiff > 0 {
            speed = (wheelTimeDiff == 0 ) ? 0 : distance! / wheelTimeDiff // m/s
          }
        }

        if( hasCrank && previousSample.hasCrank ) {
          let crankDiffTime = timeIntervalForCurrentSample(lastCrankEventTime, previous: previousSample.lastCrankEventTime)
          let valueDiff = Double(valueDiffForCurrentSample(cumulativeCrank, previous: previousSample.cumulativeCrank, max: UInt16.max))

          cadence = (crankDiffTime == 0) ? 0 : Double(60.0 * valueDiff / crankDiffTime) // RPM

        }
        print( "Cadence: \(String(describing: cadence)) RPM. Distance: \(String(describing: distance)) meters. Speed: \(String(describing: speed)) Km/h" )
        return ( cadenceinRPM:cadence, distanceinMeters:distance, speedInMetersPerSecond:speed)



      }

      var debugDescription:String {
        get {
            return "Wheel Revs: \(cumulativeWheel). Last wheel event time: \(lastWheelEventTime). Crank Revs: \(cumulativeCrank). Last Crank event time: \(lastCrankEventTime)"
        }
      }

        var myMeasurement = ((Measurement?) -> (cadenceinRPM: Double?, DistanceinMeters: Double?, speedinMetersPerSecond: Double?)).self


        struct dataVariables {

            static var mySpeed = myMeasurement.speedInMetersPerSecond


            static var myCadence : Double?
            static var miDistance : Double?

            static var myLastWheelEventTime : Double? = Measurement.valuesForPreviousMeasurement(lastWheelEventTime)

            static var myLastCrankEventTime : Double? = Measurement.valuesForPreviousMeasurement(lastCrankEventTime)


        }
    }


    }
```

and I'm trying to assign to static variables inside the struct dataVariables the returned values cadenceinRPM,distanceinMeters,speedinMetersPerSecond
as well as lastWheelEventTime and lastCrankEventTime, so I can access them in another class, but I'm having the following errors:
on var mySpeed : Instance member'myMeasurement' cannot be used on type 'Measurement'
on var myLastWheelEventTime and var myLastCrankEventTime : Instance member 'valuesForPreviousMeasurement' cannot be used on type 'Measurement' ; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?
how can a reference to those returned values than?
Can somebody explain the error? I searched for other similar questions but I'm not getting to a solution yet 
I have tried to change var myVariable to

```
var myMeasurement = Measurement.self
```

but the errors stayed the same.

and this other code

```
    //
//  CadenceSensor.swift

import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

/*
 // Bluetooth  "Cycling Speed and Cadence"
 https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServiceViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.service.cycling_speed_and_cadence.xml

 Service Cycling Speed and Cadence. Characteristic [2A5B]  // Measurement
 Service Cycling Speed and Cadence. Characteristic [2A5C]  // Supported Features
 Service Cycling Speed and Cadence. Characteristic [2A5D]  // Sensor location
 Service Cycling Speed and Cadence. Characteristic [2A55]  // Control Point

 */

public struct BTConstants {
    static let CadenceService         = "1816"
    static let CSCMeasurementUUID     = "2a5b"
    static let CSCFeatureUUID         = "2a5c"
    static let SensorLocationUUID     = "2a5d"
    static let ControlPointUUID       = "2a55"
    static let WheelFlagMask:UInt8    = 0b01
    static let CrankFlagMask:UInt8    = 0b10
    static let DefaultWheelSize:UInt32   = UInt32(myVariables.circonferenzaRuota!)  // In millimiters. 700x30 (by default my bike's wheels) :)
    static let TimeScale              = 1024.0
}

protocol CadenceSensorDelegate {

    func errorDiscoveringSensorInformation(_ error:NSError)
    func sensorReady()
    func sensorUpdatedValues( speedInMetersPerSecond speed:Double?, cadenceInRpm cadence:Double?, distanceInMeters distance:Double? )
}

class CadenceSensor: NSObject {

    let peripheral:CBPeripheral
    var sensorDelegate:CadenceSensorDelegate?
    var measurementCharasteristic:CBCharacteristic?
    var lastMeasurement:Measurement?
    let wheelCircunference:UInt32


    init(peripheral:CBPeripheral , wheel:UInt32=BTConstants.DefaultWheelSize) {
        self.peripheral = peripheral
        wheelCircunference = wheel
    }

    func start() {
        self.peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        self.peripheral.delegate = self
    }


    func stop() {
        if let measurementCharasteristic = measurementCharasteristic {
            peripheral.setNotifyValue(false, for: measurementCharasteristic)
        }

    }

    func handleValueData( _ data:Data ) {

        let measurement = Measurement(data: data, wheelSize: wheelCircunference)
        print("\(measurement)")

        let values = measurement.valuesForPreviousMeasurement(lastMeasurement)
        lastMeasurement = measurement

        sensorDelegate?.sensorUpdatedValues(speedInMetersPerSecond: values?.speedInMetersPerSecond, cadenceInRpm: values?.cadenceinRPM, distanceInMeters: values?.distanceinMeters)
    }
}



extension CadenceSensor : CBPeripheralDelegate {


    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateNotificationStateFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil else {
            sensorDelegate?.errorDiscoveringSensorInformation(NSError(domain: CBErrorDomain, code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:NSLocalizedString("Error receiving measurements updates", comment:"")]))

            return
        }
        print("notification status changed for [\(characteristic.uuid)]...")
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

        print("Updated [\(characteristic.uuid)]...")

        guard error == nil  , let data = characteristic.value  else {

            return
        }

        handleValueData(data)

    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil  else {
            sensorDelegate?.errorDiscoveringSensorInformation(error! as NSError)
            return
        }
        // Find the cadence service
        guard let cadenceService =  peripheral.services?.filter({ (service) -> Bool in
            return service.uuid == CBUUID(string: BTConstants.CadenceService)
        }).first else {

            sensorDelegate?.errorDiscoveringSensorInformation(NSError(domain: CBErrorDomain, code: NSNotFound, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:NSLocalizedString("Cadence service not found for this peripheral", comment:"")]))
            return
        }
        // Discover the cadence service characteristics
        peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for:cadenceService )
        print("Cadence service discovered")

    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

        guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else {
            sensorDelegate?.errorDiscoveringSensorInformation(NSError(domain: CBErrorDomain, code: NSNotFound, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:NSLocalizedString("No characteristics found for the cadence service", comment:"")]))
            return

        }

        print("Received characteristics");

        // Enable notifications for the measurement characteristic
        for characteristic in characteristics {

            print("Service \(service.uuid). Characteristic [\(characteristic.uuid)]")

            if characteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: BTConstants.CSCMeasurementUUID) {

                print("Found measurement characteristic. Subscribing...")
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
                measurementCharasteristic  = characteristic

            }
        }
        sensorDelegate?.sensorReady()

    }

}
```

and this other code

```
    //
//  MainViewController.swift
//  BicycleSpeed


import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class MainViewController: UIViewController {


  struct Constants {

    static let ScanSegue = "ScanSegue"
    static let SensorUserDefaultsKey = "lastsensorused"
  }

  var bluetoothManager:BluetoothManager!
  var sensor:CadenceSensor?
  weak var scanViewController:ScanViewController?
  var infoViewController:InfoTableViewController?
  var accumulatedDistance:Double?

  lazy var distanceFormatter:LengthFormatter = {

    let formatter = LengthFormatter()
    formatter.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1

    return formatter
  }()

  //@IBOutlet var labelBTStatus:UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var scanItem:UIBarButtonItem!
  @IBOutlet weak var idLabel: UILabel!


  override func viewDidLoad() {

      bluetoothManager = BluetoothManager()
      bluetoothManager.bluetoothDelegate = self
      scanItem.isEnabled = false

  }

  deinit {
    disconnectSensor()
  }

  @IBAction func unwindSegue( _ segue:UIStoryboardSegue ) {
      bluetoothManager.stopScan()
    guard let sensor = (segue as? ScanUnwindSegue)?.sensor else {
      return
    }
    print("Need to connect to sensor \(sensor.peripheral.identifier)")
    connectToSensor(sensor)

  }

  func disconnectSensor( ) {
    if sensor != nil  {
      bluetoothManager.disconnectSensor(sensor!)
      sensor = nil
    }
    accumulatedDistance = nil
  }

  func connectToSensor(_ sensor:CadenceSensor) {

    self.sensor  = sensor
    bluetoothManager.connectToSensor(sensor)
    // Save the sensor ID
    UserDefaults.standard.set(sensor.peripheral.identifier.uuidString, forKey: Constants.SensorUserDefaultsKey)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

  }
  // TODO: REconnect. Try this every X seconds
  func checkPreviousSensor() {

    guard let sensorID = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: Constants.SensorUserDefaultsKey)  as? String else {
      return
    }
    guard let sensor = bluetoothManager.retrieveSensorWithIdentifier(sensorID) else {
      return
    }
    self.sensor = sensor
    connectToSensor(sensor)

  }

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let infoVC = segue.destination as? InfoTableViewController {
        infoViewController = infoVC
    }
    if segue.identifier == Constants.ScanSegue {

        // Scan segue
      bluetoothManager.startScan()
      scanViewController  = (segue.destination as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers.first as? ScanViewController
    }

  }

}

extension MainViewController : CadenceSensorDelegate {

  func errorDiscoveringSensorInformation(_ error: NSError) {
      print("An error ocurred disconvering the sensor services/characteristics: \(error)")
  }

  func sensorReady() {
    print("Sensor ready to go...")
    accumulatedDistance = 0.0
  }

  func updateSensorInfo() {
    let name = sensor?.peripheral.name ?? ""
    let uuid = sensor?.peripheral.identifier.uuidString ?? ""

    OperationQueue.main.addOperation { () -> Void in
      self.infoViewController?.showDeviceName(name , uuid:uuid )
    }
  }


  func sensorUpdatedValues( speedInMetersPerSecond speed:Double?, cadenceInRpm cadence:Double?, distanceInMeters distance:Double? ) {

    accumulatedDistance? += distance ?? 0
    let distanceText = (accumulatedDistance != nil && accumulatedDistance! >= 1.0) ? distanceFormatter.string(fromMeters: accumulatedDistance!) : "N/A"
    let speedText = (speed != nil) ? distanceFormatter.string(fromValue: speed!*3.6, unit: .kilometer) + NSLocalizedString("/h", comment:"(km) Per hour") : "N/A"
    let cadenceText = (cadence != nil) ? String(format: "%.2f %@",  cadence!, NSLocalizedString("RPM", comment:"Revs per minute") ) : "N/A"

    OperationQueue.main.addOperation { () -> Void in

      self.infoViewController?.showMeasurementWithSpeed(speedText , cadence: cadenceText, distance: distanceText )
    }
  }


}

extension MainViewController : BluetoothManagerDelegate {

  func stateChanged(_ state: CBCentralManagerState) {
    print("State Changed: \(state)")
    var enabled = false
    var title = ""
    switch state {
    case .poweredOn:
        title = "Bluetooth ON"
        enabled = true
        // When the bluetooth changes to ON, try to reconnect to the previous sensor
        checkPreviousSensor()

    case .resetting:
        title = "Reseeting"
    case .poweredOff:
      title = "Bluetooth Off"
    case .unauthorized:
      title = "Bluetooth not authorized"
    case .unknown:
      title = "Unknown"
    case .unsupported:
      title = "Bluetooth not supported"
    }
    infoViewController?.showBluetoothStatusText( title )
    scanItem.isEnabled = enabled
  }


  func sensorConnection( _ sensor:CadenceSensor, error:NSError?) {
      print("")
    guard error == nil else {
      self.sensor = nil
      print("Error connecting to sensor: \(sensor.peripheral.identifier)")
      updateSensorInfo()
      accumulatedDistance = nil
      return
    }
    self.sensor = sensor
    self.sensor?.sensorDelegate = self
    print("Sensor connected. \(String(describing: sensor.peripheral.name)). [\(sensor.peripheral.identifier)]")
    updateSensorInfo()

    sensor.start()
  }


  func sensorDisconnected( _ sensor:CadenceSensor, error:NSError?) {
    print("Sensor disconnected")
    self.sensor = nil
  }

  func sensorDiscovered( _ sensor:CadenceSensor ) {
      scanViewController?.addSensor(sensor)
  }



}
```

in MainViewController.swift, there is this func sensorUpdatedValues that converts the three values that I want, to strings and initialize the the func showMeasurementWithSpeed ins the InfoTableViewController.swift .

Could I just return the three values inside function sensorUpdateValues  instead to be able to store them into  new variables?

Comment: There are multiple ways to share data between classes, but I'm failing to understand why you'd want to make these static vars inside your type. This is not a very Swifty solution

Comment: @Andras M. 
well those returned values I want them to be displayed in labels in a  ViewController associated to another class InfoViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way to solve this is by passing on the sensor object to the InfoTableViewController in the prepare(forSegue:) and then inside InfoTableViewControlleryou can call sensor.lastMeasurement.speedInMetersPerSecond or any other var that is inside there. Since the class is passed on by reference it will retain the data even when you transition to a new ViewController.

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if let infoVC = segue.destination as? InfoTableViewController {
    infoVC.sensor = self.sensor
}
if segue.identifier == Constants.ScanSegue {

    // Scan segue
  bluetoothManager.startScan()
  scanViewController  = (segue.destination as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers.first as? ScanViewController
}
```

}
Then of course you can do whatever you want with this data in the new VC( assign the values to labels or whatnot)

Comment: @ Andras M. 
Thanks, I think I found the right way of doing it.

I edited the question. do you think that's the right way to obtain those values? because as far as I understood this whole  project, in the 
func sensor sensorUpdatedValues inside MainViewController.swift body, after it converts the three values to strings,  there is  an addOperation that calls a function inside the InfoTableViewControler, passing the converted values as input values. and than the InfoTableViewController does build the view displays the values accordingly. right?

Comment: @Vinny Twice: I think I finally understood your intent :) the last measurement data is part of the sensor variable you have in MainViewController. What you should do is pass on the sensor from MainViewController to infoViewController. You can do it by adding a new var inside infoViewController called sensor, then in MainViewController you find the prepare function and change it like this:
`  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let infoVC = segue.destination as? InfoTableViewController {
        infoVC.sensor = self.sensor
    }`

Comment: Then you should get sensor.lastMeasurement.speedInMetersPerSecond and so on. You get the idea.

Comment: @AndrasM.I'm trying to get rid of the InfoTableViewController, and use  InfoSpeedoViewController instead with labels inside, so I should change 
var infoViewController:InfoTableViewController? to var infoViewController:InfoViewController?
and inside your edited prepare(for segue:) change
 InfoTableViewController to InfoSpeedoViewController. right?
and inside infoSpeedoViewController create a var sensor = ? What type this would be?

than to display a value inside a label it would be
speedInfoLabel.text = sensor.lastMeasurement.speedInMetersPerSecond.
did I get everything right?

Comment: Yeah that seems right. Set sensor to type CadenceSensor!

Comment: I did the changes but I had to add, inside InfoSpeedoViewController,  four functions ( showBluetoothStatusText, showDeviceName, showMeasurementWithSpeed, showDetailText ) that where present in the old InfoTableViewController, as I was getting the has non member error. When I declare speedDisplayLabel.text! = sensor.lastMeasurement.speedInMetersPerSecond inside viewDidLoad or showMeasurementWithSpeed the I get the error " Value of type  'Measurement?'  has no member 'speedInMetersperSecond',

Comment: Use sensor.lastMeasurement.valuesForPreviousMeasurement.speedInMetersPerSecond (function valuesForPreviousMeasurement returns multiple values cadenceinRPM:cadence, distanceinMeters:distance, speedInMetersPerSecond:speed)  and don't forget to convert the values to String.

Comment: I did write it like this: speedDisplayLabel.text! = String(sensor.lastMeasurement?.valuesForPreviousMeasurement.speedInM‌​etersPerSecond) but it trows an error : Value of type'(Measurement?) -> (cadenceinRPM: Double?, distanceinMeters: Double?, speedinMetersPerSecond: Double?)?' Has no member 'speedinMetersPerSecond'.

if instead write: speedDisplayLabel.text! = String(sensor.lastMeasurement?.valuesForPreviousMeasurement(<#T##previousSample: Measurement?##Measurement?#>)) I'm not sure what to type inside " previousSample: Measurement" placeholder...

Comment: You’re missing the () after valuesForPreviousMeasurement. It is a function if you skip the () it returns the function itself without calling it.

Comment: speedDisplayLabel.text! = String(sensor.lastMeasurement?.valuesForPreviousMeasurement().speedInM‌​etersPerSecond) trows error: Missing argument for parameter #1.  inserting it. becomes:
speedDisplayLabel.text! = String(sensor.lastMeasurement?.valuesForPreviousMeasurement(<#Measurement?#>).speedInM‌​etersPerSecond) + 2nd fix, it becomes: speedDisplayLabel.text! = String(describing: sensor.lastMeasurement?.valuesForPreviousMeasurement(<#Measurement?#>)?.speedInMetersPerSecond). Still can't find what to put inside placeholder Measurement.

Comment: putting Measurement? it throws the error: 
Cannot convert value of type'(Measurement?).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you have that func declared as an instance level function rather than a class/struct level function.  You should be able to simply add the "static" keyword to make it accessible for the way you are using it in your sample code.  i.e. "static func valuesForPreviousMeasurement ..."

** UPDATE - Added a simple example to show the difference between class and instance functions.

```
// This is an instance function being used.  It's called such because
// you need an actual object instance in order to call the func.
var myCar: Car = Car()
myCar.startEngine()

// This is a class level function being used.  It's called such because
// you don't actually need an object instance: It's simply part of the class.
Car.PriceForModel("HondaCivic")
```

Comment: unfortunately declaring the function as static didn't solve it, it actually throwed the same error on hasCrank and hasWeel as well as on valueDiffForCurrentSample

Comment: I copied your code into xcode, and my answer does correct the error you mentioned, but you have multiple other issues.  When you make it static, you can no longer access other variables the same way inside your valuesForPreviousMeasurment func.  If I comment the body of that method, your original error goes away.  You need to figure out if you want this to be class level, or instance level.

Comment: I also had to comment out your mySpeed variable which has yet another issue related to how you declared myMeasurement as a block.

Comment: @ ghostatron
well yes.. if I comment out the parts on which it gets errors , the errors go away, but I need them. as for your solution , declaring the function as static didn't make errors go away or change, it just add the same kind of error on more parts of the codes described. I'm on Xcode 9.1 , can it be a different version of swift we're using? I noticed I was on swift 4.0 but changing it to sift 3.2 made no difference.

Comment: I'm saying the issue is that in one place you use it like a class func, and other places like an instance func.  You defined it as an instance func, which is why it works in the func and not where you currently use it as a class func.  If you define it as static (a class func), then it will work where you now have an error but not inside the method that uses it as an instance method. That's why I said you need to decide on one and stick with it.  I mentioned commenting the function body out in order to prove it DOES fix your current error.

Comment: ok, I see the difference now. thank you ghostatron. It would be helpful maybe to see that code in the context of where it comes from, as I'm trying to adapt a repository I forked . the original repository displays the values in a tableview, but I want to  do it inside labels in a normal view controller . 
https://github.com/vinnytwice/BicycleSpeed

Answer (score 0):

Finally Solved .. it was easier than thought.. as I was understanding the three values I'm interested in were passed some how to the infoTableViewController I wanted to get rid of. And they were passed, already converted to String with the function sensorUpdatedValues inside MainView controller

```
  func sensorUpdatedValues( speedInMetersPerSecond speed:Double?, cadenceInRpm cadence:Double?, distanceInMeters distance:Double? ) {

    accumulatedDistance? += distance ?? 0
    let distanceText = (accumulatedDistance != nil && accumulatedDistance! >= 1.0) ? distanceFormatter.string(fromMeters: accumulatedDistance!) : "N/A"
    let speedText = (speed != nil) ? distanceFormatter.string(fromValue: speed!*3.6, unit: .kilometer) + NSLocalizedString("/h", comment:"(km) Per hour") : "N/A"
    let cadenceText = (cadence != nil) ? String(format: "%.2f %@",  cadence!, NSLocalizedString("RPM", comment:"Revs per minute") ) : "N/A"



    OperationQueue.main.addOperation { () -> Void in

      self.infoViewController?.showMeasurementWithSpeed(speedText , cadence: cadenceText, distance: distanceText )
    }
  }
```

so I traced down the function inside my InfospeedoViewController ( as xCode was asking for it because it was present in InfoTableViewController and rerouting to InfoSpeedoViewController made it necessary) and inside that function's body I made the connection of the values to the labels.

```
 func showMeasurementWithSpeed( _ speed:String, cadence:String, distance:String  ) {

          speedDisplayLabel.text = speed
          cadenceDisplayLabel.text = cadence
          distanceDisplayLabel.text = distance


//        showDetailText(speed, atSection: Constants.MeasurementsSection, row:Constants.SpeedRow)
//        showDetailText(cadence, atSection: Constants.MeasurementsSection, row:Constants.CadenceRow)
//        showDetailText(distance, atSection: Constants.MeasurementsSection, row:Constants.DistanceRow)

    }
```

the commented out parts were the old InfoTableViewController indication to fill the cells..
Many thanks for your help. I learned a few things and consolidated others. I guess we went the hard way trying to catch this values in the wrong place, but I guess that just because I had all the project's file printed that I could trace the data flow easier. Not fully understanding the code because of my low knowledge of swift made it a bit more difficoult, but I had this feeling the this solution was logic as often the simple way is the best way, an often one just can't see it. 
thanks again 
I have two more values I want to get. A new adventure begins ..should I post another question or continue this one?